# Can the app 'Stickman' be run on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

Can you download with no problem the app [Stickman](https://stickman.en.softonic.com/) and not damage your Raspberry Pi (a Raspberry Pi 3 in particular)?

Another question I have is if you can play League of Legends, Hearthstone, etc.

Comment: The Pi uses what is called ARM architecture and it is completely different to the architecture your desktop computer uses. This means unless a program is built for the Pi it's not going work. Also the Pi really doesn't have the performance for playing games like league of legends anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**The quick answer:**

No, you cannot run it on the Pi at this time (same goes for the other games you mentioned).

**The full answer:**

Stickman is a Windows GUI application. It requires the full Windows OS to run properly. Unfortunately, as of this time (Dec 2017) there is not a full version of Windows that runs on the Pi, or any other ARM-processor device.  There is a [lightweight IoT version of Windows](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/windows-10-on-the-raspberry-pi-what-you-need-to-know/) that runs on the Pi, but it is not intended for running full-fledged traditional Windows applications and/or games.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If either of the following is true then yes, otherwise no.

1. It is a Linux executable built for the Pi's CPU.
2. You have the source code and it is compatible with Linux.